# Do I need to offset a pointer when calling recv?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, networking, recv

When using recv, I have always done something like this:

```
int len = 1000;
int n = 0;

char buf[1000];
while(n < len) {
  n += recv(socket, buf + n, len - n, 0);
}
```

my logic being that if recv does not recieve the full data of `len` bytes, I should only receive the rest of the bytes (`len - n`) and should not overwrite the data that is already recieved (so I offset the beginner of the buffer to the end of already received content). This seems to work perfectly fine whenever I use it.

However, most if not all examples of recv that I see simply do something like follows:

```
int len = 1000;
int n = 0;

char buf[1000];
while(n < len) {
  n += recv(socket, buf, len, 0);
}
```

Does this not leave you vulnerable to overwriting the beginning of your buffer if recv is called more than once?

Comment: "*most if not all examples of recv*'. Unless those examples are just trying to consume the data without using it or you have taken it out of context then it does look incorrect as you have stated.

Comment: Your "offset" arises because you are trying to store data from multiple calls of `recv()` into the array i.e.  you aren't always reading to the first element of the array.   The examples you refer to all read to the first character of the buffer (so data on the second and subsequent calls of `recv()` overwrites array elements that were previously received).    Both approaches are valid, but in different circumstances (i.e. there is not some magical "always do this" recipe).   In all cases, it is necessary to ensure that your code does not run past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your examples are not accounting for the possibility of `recv()` failing. You need to check the return value for errors, eg:

```cpp
char buf[1000];
int len = sizeof(buf);
int n = 0, ret;

while (n < len) {
  ret = recv(socket, buf + n, len - n, 0);
  if (ret <= 0) {
    // error handling...
    break;
  }
  n += ret;
}
```

Your 1st example is good to use when you know up front exactly how many bytes you need to read, and can pre-allocate a buffer large enough to hold it all.

Your 2nd example is good to use when you need to stream the data more dynamically, 1 buffer at a time. For instance, maybe the data is being saved to a file. Or maybe the data is too large to fit in such a small buffer and needs to be processed in chunks. Or maybe the data is appended to another dynamically growing  buffer for later use. Lots of reasons for this use-case, eg:

```cpp
char buf[1000];
int n;

while (some condition) {
  n = recv(socket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
  if (n <= 0) {
    // error handling...
    break;
  }
  // use buf up to n bytes...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's all bad.
if we're talking about C you need at least space for `\0`. you can remove it only when you're sure all is right. otherwise you couldn't test it. And all this stuff means you're not sure you can make it all in one hit so you may have say `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` there. If you don't

```cpp
int btx;
....
char x[9001] = {0};
int b = 0;
int e = 0;
do
{
   b = recv(btx, x + e, 9000, 0);
   e = e + b;
}while(b != 0);
```

And C++

```cpp
std::stringstream fbtc_b;
int btx;
....
int b = 0;
do
{
   char x[9000];
   b = recv(btx, x, 9000, 0);
   fbtc_b.write(x, b);
}while(b != 0);
```